# Unable to update value with X-editable using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, x-editable, edit-in-place

I'm using the bootstrap version of [x-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html) plugin to update the `url` value present in the table. When a user changes the values of the `select` box an ajax call is fired to retrieve the corresponding `url` for the store. Though I unbind the x-editable event everytime before updating the url value, something is not right. The url gets updated only once and then remains the same for the rest of select change events.

```
<select id="search">
    <option value='1'>store 1</option>
    <option value='2'>store 2</option>
    <option value='3'>store 3</option>
</select>

<table>
    ...
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href='#' id='url_qa'></a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

    // Select box change event
    $('#search').change(function() {
        // ajax call to load the url based on chosen select value
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'load.php',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {'id': $(this).val()},
        }).done(function(data) {
            $('#url').editable('destroy'); // destroy editable
            $('#url').editable({
                type: 'text',
                pk: 1,
                url: '/post',
                title: 'Enter username',
                value: data['url']
            });
        }).fail(function() {
            alert('Error: Unable to fetch information for the chosen id');
        });
    });
```

**The following happens when I change my select value**

- When I change the select value for the first time, the url is empty and does not get updated.
- But when I change the select value for the second time the url is gets changed.
- And for all select value changes after this the second url is not updated at all.

Demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38o7e58x/3/)

Comment: you have extra ending tag in your script.

Comment: Is it going to the `fail()` statement? on second change.

Comment: And in the `<option>` there is a missing attribute `value`. But in ajax call, you are accessing the `<option>` value as `data`.

Comment: @Samir I had it in my code but forgot to specify in the question since it was simplified version. I corrected both of your points. :-)

Comment: you have multiple #url divs?

Comment: Yes. But I have assigned a separate `id` for each url. So when a user changes a select value I update 3 different `urls`.

Comment: @DhiwaTdG you are binding to the same id

Comment: I have posted a simplified script. FYI, the ajax update doesn't work even when I have only 1 url.

Comment: is your ajax even triggering?

Comment: Yes. I logged my ajax return `data` and it works.

Comment: can you provide a working jsfiddle?

Comment: Added a jsfiddle link.

Comment: @madalinivascu Please check the updated jsfiddle link.